# Disable autoplay on audio in html and/or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to coding & new to stackoverflow! I've got about 30 hours of coding under my belt so far and my efforts are what you might call the 'Frankenstein Method'. Hopefully I can get some advice and a solution to my problem...

So... I'm attempting to build a website & I've managed to code an audioplayer with a playlist using HTML5, CSS and javascript BUT the audio plays automatically when the page opens and I don't want this to happen!

I've tried using various snippets such as autoplay="false" and autostart="false" in the HTML and javascript but nothing seems to be working. Please help!

I've attached my code for reference - all feedback is welcome as I'm keen to learn but as mentioned I am new to coding and need to improve my skills fast!

Thank you in advance!

```js
// P1.js
function audioPlayer(){
        var currentSong = 0;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
        $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault(); 
           $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
           $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
           $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
            currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
            $(this).parent().addClass("current-song");
        });

        $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
           currentSong++;
            if(currentSong == $("#playlist li a").length)
                currentSong = 0;
            $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
            $("#playlist li:eq("+currentSong+")").addClass("current-song");
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[currentSong].href;
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
        });
    }

// Inline script

// loads the audio player
audioPlayer("P1.js");
```

```css
.playernh {
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px;
    top: 1050px;
    list-style: none;
    height:75px;
    width:400px;
    background-color: pink;
}
#playlist li a {
    font-family: "Courier New";
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: red;
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#playlist .current-song a {
    color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="playernh">

<audio id="audioPlayer" controls="controls">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support html5!
</audio>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li class="current-song"><a href="Schietwetter - Naked Healer - 01 Naked Healer.mp3">Naked Healer</a></li>
    <li><a href="Schietwetter - Naked Healer - 02 Brown Matter.mp3">Brown Matter</a></li>
    <li><a href="Schietwetter - Naked Healer - 03 Maos.mp3">Maos</a></li>
    <li><a href="Schietwetter - Naked Healer - 04 Schwerlast.mp3">Schwerlast</a></li>
    <li><a href="Schietwetter - Naked Healer - 05 Swallow.mp3">Swallow</a></li>
    <li><a href="Schietwetter - Naked Healer - 06 Tanzer.mp3">Tanzer</a></li>
    <li><a href="Schietwetter - Naked Healer - 07 Edwards War.mp3">Edwards War</a></li>
    <li><a href="Schietwetter - Naked Healer - 08 Substanz.mp3">Substanz</a></li>
    <li><a href="Schietwetter - Naked Healer - 09 Wolfkopf.mp3">Wolfkopf</a></li>
    <li><a href="Schietwetter - Naked Healer - 10 Boni.mp3">Boni</a></li>
    <li><a href="Schietwetter - Naked Healer - 11 Moth.mp3">Moth</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `audioPlayer` immediately, and `audioPlayer`...

```
function audioPlayer(){
  var currentSong = 0;
  $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
  $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
```

...immediately starts playing music. Take out the `.src` and `.play` lines there. (Leave them in the `click` handler, though!)

<sub>Also, `audioPlayer` doesn't take an argument. Once your Javascript starts running, the browser has already slammed all of your scripts together in one long mess of code. There's no notion of `"p1.js"` at that point.</sub>

Comment: This has done the trick! I removed the two lines identified above and the autoplay function has now ceased.